# What is wrong with the following induction argument?

Tags: proof-verification, induction, contest-math

I found a problem on a note on induction. The problem went like this:

"Let $n$ be a non-negative integer. Suppose we are given a triangle and n points inside it, with no three of
the given $n + 3$ points collinear. We divide the triangle into smaller triangles, using the $n + 3$ points as vertices.
Show that we always end up with $2n + 1$ triangles."

A proposed solution followed the problem:

"For the base case $n = 0$, there is clearly $2n + 1 = 1$ triangle. For the inductive step, assume that $k$ points
inside the triangle define $2k + 1$ triangles. If we add a point $x$, as shown, then we lose one triangle but create three
more triangles, for a net addition of two triangles. Hence, there are a total of $2k + 1 + 2 = 2k + 3 = 2(k + 1) + 1$
triangles, which completes the induction."

[image: A picture that explains the argument]

According to the note, this solution has a 'major conceptual flaw' and I can't seem to find it. Is it the base case?

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: "divide" how? why are there no line segments between the point $x$ and all of the other points?

Comment: @oseiskar: the problem contains the implicit assumption that the line segments don't intersect. That is what the problem means by 'dividing the triangle'.

Comment: I still don't think the "division" is well-defined. There are many ways of "connecting the dots" so that the lines do not intersect. You can, for example, remove the vertical line in the second picture and draw a horizontal line from $x$ to the point on the left. You might not be able to construct this partition using the process described in the proof, however. If the question concerns any partition where the lines do not intersect, then this might be your answer.

Comment: @oseiskar: I see. I think, by 'division', the problem means one of the various configurations possible by joining the points without letting the segments intersect one another. However, I still don't see what's wrong with this. By the induction hypothesis, a configuration of $2k+1$ triangles exists for $k$ points inside the triangle. Adding another one would take away one triangle and add three more. Still confused about why this has a flaw.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The statement we are to prove is not that we *can* partition the triangle into $2n + 1$ triangles using the $n + 3$ points as described.
Rather, it says that if we *do* partition the triangle using the $n + 3$ points as described,
the result will always be $2n + 1$ triangles.

The argument fails because there are partitions of the triangle that can be done using some sets of $n + 3$ points that cannot be derived by the method given in the "proof."
Therefore we don't know that the statement holds for those partitions.

Here is a partition of a triangle for the case $n = 3$ that cannot be generated by adding one point to an existing partition for the case $n = 2$:

[image]

The construction in the "proof" can generate only partitions in which at least one of the additional $n$ vertices has only three edges meeting at it.

As it so happens, this example is still a partition into $2n + 1$ triangles, but there is nothing in the "proof" to say that this is more than a happy coincidence, or that it will continue to hold true for partitions of larger sets of points that the construction of the "proof" cannot generate.

Comment: Ah! That makes sense. Thanks!